# How to resolve the ambiguity of the function in qt slot

Tags: qt, qt5

I want to connect a function to a slot and this is my code.

I get error that no instance of overloaded function matched the argument list.

```
connect(lineEditCommandInterface, &QLineEdit::textChanged, this, &SUMMIT::ReceiveCommand);
```

the issue is that ReceiveCommand is a overloaded function and i want to use the function with no arguments.

```
  void ReceiveCommand();
  void ReceiveCommand( std::string stdstrCommand);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to use a lambda function:

```cpp
connect(lineEditCommandInterface, &QLineEdit::textChanged, [this](){
   ReceiveCommand(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Aanother option could be static casting the slot, just in case you may skip the lambda....

```
slots:
void fooSlot(int x);
void fooSlot(const QString& n);
```

then

```
connect(someObject, &SomeClass::someSignal, this, static_cast<void(MainWindow::*)(const QString&)>(&MainWindow::fooSlot));
connect(someObject, &SomeClass::someSignal, this, static_cast<void(MainWindow::*)(int)>(&MainWindow::fooSlot));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Qt 5.6, the recommended (or at least less verbose) way to connect to overloaded signals/slots is with `QOverload::of()` (which isn't well documented).  With Qt 5.7+ and C++14 one can also use [`qOverload()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qOverload) and friends. Though this doesn't help with mismatched signal/slot parameters, it seems worth pointing out.

Example with C++11 and `QOverload`:

`connect(object, &SomeClass::someSignal, this, QOverload<void>::of(&SUMMIT::ReceiveCommand));`

The various options are documented with examples (including the old `static_cast` method) in: [Selecting Overloaded Signals and Slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots-syntaxes.html#selecting-overloaded-signals-and-slots)

Also of possible interest in regards to this question is the section in the same doc: [Using Default Parameters in Slots to Connect to Signals with Fewer Parameters](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots-syntaxes.html#using-default-parameters-in-slots-to-connect-to-signals-with-fewer-parameters). The lambda option is also documented higher up on that page.

Further examples of using `QOverload` can be found in Qt docs for just about every overloaded signal, (eg. [`SpinBox::valueChanged()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html#valueChanged-1)) but it also works for slots.